# Is it possible to get a hash of merge commit before merge?

Tags: git

Let's say I have 2 branches - master and feature. Also I have a pull request with 2 commits from feature to master.
If I merge it I ll have a merge commit.
Is this commit already configured somehow before merge? Can I look at it somehow? I know that I can get hash of refs/pull-requests/1/from and refs/pull-requests/1/merge branches, but can I get something like "merge" commit?

Comment: What are you actually trying to *achieve* here? What's the problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: If you want to have a shot at inspecting / testing the resulting state of a merge before issuing a pull request, do it locally. If you like the results, go for your pull request.

Comment: for what purpose do you need merge commit for? it will only comprise of changes that you have merged from feature.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### First, let's answer the question you didn't know to ask

> ... I know that I can get hash of `refs/pull-requests/1/from` and `refs/pull-requests/1/merge` branches, but can I get something like "merge" commit?

These are not Git features, these are Bitbucket features.  (It's possible some other web service uses the same technique, but I will assume Bitbucket here.)  See https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Bitbucket-questions/Difference-of-refs-pull-requests-lt-ID-gt-merge-and-refs-pull/qaq-p/772142 (and note the caveats in that question's answer).

These two are technically not *branches*, except that this depends on how we define the word *branch*.  See [What exactly do we mean by "branch"?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25068543/1256452)  But they are commit hash IDs.  The hash ID given by `refs/pull-requests/1/from` always exists and is the tip commit of the series of commits that whoever made PR#1 had when they made the Pull Request.  The name `refs/pull-requests/1/merge` *may not exist*, but if it does exist, it is the hash ID of a merge commit that Bitbucket already made.  This is the result of the test merge that Bitbucket tried, to see whether or not the pull request can be merged as-is.

If the merge commit already exists, you can retrieve it into your own Git repository.  Note that if it *does* exist, that means Bitbucket's Git was able to resolve the merge without human assistance.  You can therefore have *your* Git do the same, if that is easier or more convenient than obtaining *their* merge.  While you'll get a different merge *commit*, it will have the same associated *tree:* see below.

#### Why the original question is a little silly

The hash ID of a commit is computed by hashing the contents of the commit.

Here are the contents of a sample commit (but with `@` changed to  to maybe possibly decrease someone's spam-load):

```
tree a830f927ccaf7164b03602729cc7078c79d5bbf2
parent fab4a8a39666793d407371f519e8b6d25d33fa84
author Junio C Hamano <gitster pobox.com> 1558252002 +0900
committer Junio C Hamano <gitster pobox.com> 1558252002 +0900

Git 2.22-rc1

Signed-off-by: Junio C Hamano <gitster pobox.com>
```

Note that the *tree* of a merge (the hash ID after the word `tree` here) is unknown until after doing the merge, but you could do the merge to find the tree and then you will know the tree.

The above is a non-merge commit; here's a merge commit:

```
tree ea8851107dda1a726b3eec91d347996ead1ab683
parent 8c59ba9a764f1ae1f8d176ea17c636183cfd7267
parent f3a3a021c716b46ed35e6b7171bbff4d8042da68
author Junio C Hamano <gitster pobox.com> 1558251935 +0900
committer Junio C Hamano <gitster pobox.com> 1558251935 +0900

Merge branch 'js/difftool-no-index'

The "--dir-diff" mode of "git difftool" is not useful in "--no-index"
mode; they are now explicitly marked as mutually incompatible.

* js/difftool-no-index:
  difftool --no-index: error out on --dir-diff (and don't crash)
```

The key difference is that the merge has two parents.  The *parents* of the merge are obvious: the first one is the current commit before you do the merge, and the other is hash ID of the commit you intend to merge.

After the `tree` and `parent` lines, though, come the `author` and `committer` lines.  These not only contain a known quantity—the name and email address—but also an unpredictable one: the exact second at which the merge is done (`1558252002` for instance).

The rest of the merge commit contents are the commit message, which presumably you know.

So, in order to predict the merge, you need to:

- Perform the merge, to find the `tree`
- Predict the time at which you'll do the merge later

Once you know these two bits of data, you can fill out the header contents and compute the hash ID of the merge.

Of course, that first step—*perform the merge*—now suffices: you *have* the merge; so just use it.  This is also why Bitbucket perform a test merge—as do GitHub, though *their* names are `refs/pull/number/head` and `refs/pull/number/merge`.